# grafana timeseries chart from mysql json data

Tags: mysql, json, grafana

my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_data (
  `item_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `data_json` json NOT NULL
);
```

says that i inserted this data into the table:

```sql
INSERT INTO item_data VALUES
(1, NOW(), '{"value": 21.9}'),
(2, NOW(), '{"value": 22.9}'),
(1, NOW(), '{"value": 21.5}'),
(2, NOW(), '{"value": 22.5}');
```

i wanted to populate below query to grafana as a `graph` chart:

```sql
SELECT
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_time) time, 
CAST(item_id AS CHAR) metric,
data_json->>'$.value' value
FROM item_data;
```

Using `JSON_TYPE` on `data_json->>'$.value'` says that this extract will result to `DOUBLE` data type. However grafana will throw an error `Value column must have numeric datatype, column: value type: string value: 21.9`

Are there any way to map the data to `graph visualization`?

Comment: Not related to the solution but I think `CAST(item_id AS VARCHAR)` should be replaced with `CAST(item_id AS CHAR)`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan oh yes it should be CHAR